# Variable giving me undefined index off 0

Tags: php

I'm currently building a social network. I got to the point where I need cookies and tokens (in the database) to make people logout and login in.

The problem is that for some reason one of my variables is not getting any data from the query I wrote...

Here's the code of the page:

Cookie_login.php

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

class Login
{
    public static function isloggedIn(): ?int
    {
        if (isset($_COOKIE['SNID'])) {
            $user = DB::query(
                'SELECT  user_id FROM tokens WHERE token=:token',
                [':token' => sha1($_COOKIE['SNID'])]
            );

            if (empty($user) && isset($user[0]['user_id'])) {
                $userid = $user[0]['user_id'];
            }
            if (isset($_COOKIE['SNID_'])) {
                return $userid;
            }
            $cstrong = true;
            $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
            DB_update::query_update(
                'INSERT INTO tokens VALUES (\'\',:token,:user_id)',
                [':token' => sha1($token), ':user_id' => $userid]
            );
            DB_update::query_update('DELETE FROM tokens WHERE token=:token', [':token' => sha1($_COOKIE['SNID'])]);

            setcookie('SNID', $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/', null, true, true);

            return $userid;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and the DB.php

```php
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class DB
{
    private static function connect(): PDO
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=pap;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo;
    }

    public static function query($query, $params = [])
    {
        $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($params);
        return $statement->fetchALL();
    }
}

class DB_update
{
    private static function connect(): PDO
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=pap;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo;
    }

    public static function query_update($query_update, $paramss = [])
    {
        $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query_update);
        $statement->execute($paramss);
        return $statement->RowCount();
    }
}
```

I used the `fopen()` and `fwrite()` to see what `$userid` is returning and it was returning 1... Already check the queries in SQL and they work just fine... So I don't know why the `$userid` variable is not saving the user_id from the table. I hope you guys can help me...
PS:`DB_update` is just a name to be different from `DB_query`

Comment: Probably want to remove `empty($user)`

Comment: @AbraCadaver I get the same output... ```$userid``` returns ```NULL```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line generates your "undefined index off 0" error:

```
$userid = DB::query('SELECT  user_id FROM tokens WHERE token=:token', 
        array(':token' =>sha1($_COOKIE['SNID'])))[0]['user_id'];
```

Specifically, the `[0]['user_id']` bit that you've patched to the end of the query. You should only ever do that if you're sure the function called will *always* return an array with the necessary fields (not the case with DB queries!). When there is no match, your `DB::query` method probably returns `NULL` or `false` (and you can't have `NULL[0]` etc. much less `NULL[0]['user_id']`, thus the error).

You'll want to postpone the offset assignment, and first of all have a logic for situations where no match happens. First put the DB query result into a variable that you can evaluate as being the expected type of resource or not -- only then assign array offsets.

```
$user = DB::query('SELECT  user_id FROM tokens WHERE token=:token', 
        array(':token' =>sha1($_COOKIE['SNID'])));

if (!empty($user) && isset($user[0]['user_id'])) {
    $userid = $user[0]['user_id'];
}
else {
    // whatever that you need to do here.
}
```

On your debugging trouble; your `print_r` logger is only logging `1` because:

```
 print_r ( mixed $expression [, bool $return = FALSE ] ) : mixed
 
... "When the $return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string.
Otherwise, the return value is TRUE."
```

If you want to both print and log into a file, then use an intermediate variable, along the lines of `$pr = print_r($foo, true); echo $pr; fwrite($fp, $pr);`. Hope that helps you get it sorted.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer! the undefined index offset 0 did go away, but ```$userid``` seems not getting any data too... the error says Undefined variable: userid in D:\xampp\htdocs\site\classes\cookie_login.php on line 16... maybe my ```DB::query``` isnt properly written? Also I edited the code with your  code answer

Comment: Since you didn't fill in anything into the `else { // ..your fallback logic here }`, for sure you will still get errors if you attempt to use an undefined variable. Where does `$userid` come from, if not from the DB? ... Onward, to debug your query, `echo sha1($_COOKIE['SNID'])` and make sure there's actually a token matching that string in your database. Also, what's `var_dump($user);` giving you, now that you've updated the code? (Rather use `var_dump` so you can tell booleans from 0 and 1, and NULL from false, etc.)

Comment: So, I put ```var_dump($user);``` in the ```else {//something}``` and got this ```array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["user_id"]=> string(2) "26" [0]=> string(2) "26" } } ``` which it seems correct since the user that is logged in has a ```user_id ``` of 26... So why is not ```$userid``` saving that?

Comment: Your current code reads `if (empty($user) && isset($user[0]['user_id'])) {`, it should be `!empty(` ie. "not empty" === we are getting an actual result from the query. The `else {}` section is where you'd deal with an empty query result.

Comment: Oh, that was because I was getting an error still, so I start to try out somethings but now the ```var_dump```` shows this ```array(0) { } ```  after the change... Isnt worst now? the other one was showing the right ```user_id``` this one shows empty... which doesnt make sense since the if statement is to prevent the ```userid``` being empty right?

Comment: The conditional check assigns `$userid` on the basis of the MySQL result. If you put the `var_dump` inside the `if` part, you will see the output of a successful query. The `else` part is iterated when there is no result from the query. Your original error (undefined index) is triggered in situations where there's no result from the query.

Comment: You're right!! also I saw that my braces were positioned wrong. Thats why the variable was undefined... Thanks a lot! I will give you the solution to the answer

Answer (score 1):

First, of all:

```
fwrite($fp, print_r($userid));
```

Function [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) has a second parameter, default sets to `false` but in your case, you have to explicity set to `true`:

```
fwrite($fp, print_r($userid, true));
```

Otherwise, you will always write to file `1` value.

And the second. It's good idea to use function [`fclose`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose) to close opened file pointer if it's no longer required.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, yeah now its ouputing me nothing... so how do I fix that? the ```$userid``` outputing nothing

Comment: Give me a few minutes. I will try to rewrite and simplify...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's whole code with comments:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

class DB
{
    private static function connect()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=pap;charset=utf8','root','');
        $pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo;
    }

    public static function query($query,$params=array())
    {
        $statement = self::connect() ->prepare($query);
        $statement ->execute($params);
       
        $data = $statement -> fetchALL();
        return $data;


    }
}   

class DB_update
{
    private static function connect()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=pap;charset=utf8','root','');
        $pdo -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo;
    }

    public static function query_update($query_update,$paramss=array())
    {
        $statement = self::connect() ->prepare($query_update);
        $statement ->execute($paramss);
        $datas = $statement -> RowCount();
        return $datas;    
    }
}

/**
 * Table `tokens` schema:
 * CREATE TABLE `tokens` (
 * `token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 * `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 * PRIMARY KEY (`token`)
 * ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
 */

class Login
{
    public static function isloggedIn()
    {
        if (isset($_COOKIE['SNID'])) {
            $userid = DB::query('SELECT user_id FROM tokens WHERE token=:token',array(':token' =>sha1($_COOKIE['SNID'])))[0]['user_id'];

            $fp = fopen('problem.txt', 'w');
            fwrite($fp, print_r($userid, true));
            fclose($fp);

            // I don't understand, what is this ? There is no place in your code, to set that cookie in that named key
            // It always be false
            if (isset($_COOKIE['SNID_'])) 
            {
                return $userid;   
            }
            else {
                $cstrong = TRUE;
                $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
                DB_update::query_update('INSERT INTO tokens VALUES (:token,:user_id)',array(':token'=>sha1($token),':user_id'=>$userid));
                DB_update::query_update('DELETE FROM tokens WHERE token=:token',array(':token'=>sha1($_COOKIE['SNID'])));

                setcookie("SNID", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/', NULL, TRUE, TRUE);

                // I don't understand what is this below
                setcookie("SNID:", '1', time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 3, '/', NULL, TRUE, TRUE);

                return $userid;   
            }       
        }
      
        return false;
    }
}

// Uncomment code below to log in
// $userIdToLogIn = 19; // You can change it to any other value
// $cstrong = true;
// $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
// DB_update::query_update('INSERT INTO tokens VALUES (:token, :user_id)', array(':token' => sha1($token), ':user_id' => $userIdToLogIn));
// setcookie("SNID", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/', NULL, TRUE, TRUE);
// ------------------------------

// Uncomment code below to log out
// setcookie("SNID", time() - 3600);
// -------------------------------


// And check
$userId = Login::isloggedIn();
if($userId) {
    printf(
        "User with id: %s is logger in with token: %s",
        $userId,
        DB::query('SELECT token FROM tokens WHERE user_id = :user_id', array(':user_id' => $userId))[0]['token']
    );
} else {
    echo "User is not logger in!";
}
```

And now:

1. Uncomment lines for comment: `Uncomment code below to log in` for first request. Script log in you.
2. Comment it back for second and nexts requests to check how it works.

Comment: The code looks much better now, but it still gives me this error:: Undefined offset: 0 in D:\xampp\htdocs\site\classes\cookie_login.php on line 7... it seems like ```$userid``` is getting no data

Comment: Clear all cookies from browser for your domain. Probably you have once for `SNID`.

Comment: Yeah but a cookie is created when I log in... and to logout it should be deleted but when I try to logout if gives me that error... and it also says that ```user_id``` cant be null which means that ```$userid``` isn't returning data

Comment: Probably that i have a little bit other `tokens` table schema that you. `tokens` table have only 2 columns, without first, becouse it doesn't sense for me to put there empty string. So i pasted in comments schema in my database.

Comment: oh yeah, so should I delete the first column?

Comment: I think it wont resolve the problem since the "string" thing was the id of that table

Comment: Try that. Create new database, table as i wrote, change database name in connection parameters and try again :)

Comment: Ok, so the problem was actually the code itself... But thanks a lot for the help tto